# Error using python Adafruit_BBIO GPIO with ROS on Ubuntu 14.04 (Beaglebone Black)

Tags: python, ubuntu, beagleboneblack, ros

When running ROS Indigo on the Beaglebone Black (Ubuntu 14.04 with 3.8.x Kernel) I run into a strange problem while using the Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO and Adafruit_BBIO.PWM libraries.

The Adafruit_BBIO.PWM controls my PWM pins when used with python under root rights. If I don't run it with root rights I receive a:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots'
```

However, if I try to run the ros script with root rights (apparently is not recommended), I receive:

```
File "teleop.py", line 1, in <module> 
import rospy
ImportError: No module named rospy
```

which is, I guess, because of trouble sourcing and permission rights.
With the Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO library I have a similar issue where it just does nothing when used with unprivileged rights but that seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/36).

Now running `ros` with root rights would fix my problems. On the other hand, it is not recommended. If I apply the patch for the GPIO pins and someone suggests me a fix for the permission rights issue for slots I could operate Ros under non-root rights. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to [BeagleBone Black Setup](https://github.com/sdcharle/blabs-thermostat/tree/master/BeagleBone#setup-the-temperature-sensor), you have to grant access to your device slots using this command :

```
sudo sh -c " echo BB-W1:00A0 > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots"
```

otherwise you'll get 'permission denied'.